# Need to connect to a Fortigate VPN from Linux

Tags: linux, networking, debian, vpn, vpnc

I really want to connect to a Fortigate IPsec VPN from Linux, but "it's not working" (see below).

I tried Shrewsoft first, but it wasn't compiling, and while I was searching for a fix, I heard that Shrewsoft VPN is moribund.

I've moved on to vpnc, but I'm not having much luck with that either.  My redacted config file is below, along with the error I'm getting.
It bothers me more than a little that ike-scan thinks my gateway isn't handshaking.  Also, my IT guy says there are no failed login attempts on the Fortigate side.

My vpnc config looks like:

```
IPSec gateway redacted.example.com
IPSec ID redacted
IPSec secret redacted
#IKE Authmode hybrid
IKE Authmode psk
Xauth username redacted
#Xauth password redacted
```

The error I get is:

```
$ vpnc-connect
Enter password for user@redacted.example.com:
vpnc-connect: no response from target
```

If I strace vpnc, I can see it timing out trying to poll for an answer back from udp/500 on host.example.com.

I see something similar if I try to ike-scan host.example.com:

```
Starting ike-scan 1.9.4 with 1 hosts (http://www.nta-monitor.com/tools/ike-scan/)
Ending ike-scan 1.9.4: 1 hosts scanned in 3.311 seconds (0.30 hosts/sec). 0 returned handshake; 0 returned notify
```

It's like I have the wrong server or something, but the hostname does resolve, and I can see the UDP/500 port open|filtered in the output from:

```
nmap -P0 -sU -p 500 host.example.com
```

I've got some special characters in my PSK, including a comment character, but I don't think that's supposed to matter to vpnc.

I'm on Debian 10.10. and I'm using vpnc 0.5.3r550-3

Fortigate as the server is a requirement, but we have a lot of flexibility on the client.  As long as it's Debian Linux.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Please note that the SSL VPN doesn't satisfy the requirement.  Our Fortigate is IPsec only.

Comment: I also tried NetworkManager, but it failed to establish a connection as well.

Comment: You need a Linux version of the Fortigate client app. Fortigate client conflicts with vanilla IPSec clients. We have seen this hardware at customers.

Comment: If you suspect the special characters contained within your PSK, the obvious solution, is to get rid of those special characters temporarily. Of course I would agree with your initial conclusion, the client does not even appear to even attempt a connection to the server, likely due to a client conflict.  It should be pointed out, you won't receive any software recommendations for IPsec clients, as software recommendations are specifically out of scope here at Super User.  Any (sanitized) verbose logs would be helpful.  *Verify the actual port on the VPN is 500*

Comment: Try this:   https://www.reddit.com/r/fortinet/comments/ggk02l/official_vpn_client_for_linux/

Comment: @John Fortigate has a Linux client, but it doesn't support IPsec - only SSL VPN.  But I need IPsec.  I've heard of people getting it working on Linux, but the details are scant.

Comment: @Ramhound My IT guy says UDP/500 is correct.

Comment: I'm trying LibreSwan now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not getting complete authentication, but I've cleared one hurdle and moved on to the next.

The hurdle comprising this question was cleared by adding:

```
IKE DH Group dh5
```

...to:

```
/etc/vpnc/default.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

vpnc worked with ipsec to me, my config is:

- IPSec gateway yourgatewayip
- IPSec ID youripsecid
- IPSec secret youripsecsecret
- Xauth username yourusername
- Xauth password yourpass
  IKE DH Group dh5
- Perfect Forward Secrecy dh5
- Interface name myvpn-ike

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).